# Is there difference between send(:method_name) and method(:method_name).call?

Tags: ruby

Is there difference between `send` and `method().call` in ruby?

```
1.send(:to_f)
=> 1.0
1.method(:to_f).call
=> 1.0
```

Both seems same for me though.

Answer (score 10):

From your perspective, they do the same thing. But the version with `method` is significantly slower (because it does more stuff "behind the scenes", like creating a method object)

```
require 'benchmark/ips'

Benchmark.ips do |x|
  x.report('plain send') do |times|
    1.send(:to_f)
  end
  x.report('method with call') do |times|
    1.method(:to_f).call
  end

  x.compare!
end
```

### Result

```
Calculating -------------------------------------
          plain send   142.776k i/100ms
    method with call    73.266k i/100ms
-------------------------------------------------
          plain send    143.863B (±17.0%) i/s -    178.678B
    method with call     73.358B (±18.1%) i/s -    106.276B

Comparison:
          plain send: 143862537517.5 i/s
    method with call: 73358071888.5 i/s - 1.96x slower
```